# Upgrade Replication MySQL from 5.7.34 to 8.0.28 without database downtime

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0, upgrade

I have to upgrade a MySQL replication topology from 5.7 to 8.0 without database downtime. It’s MySQL Community Edition.

There is one source and 5 replicas in the topology and connections happen via ProxySQL Cluster of  3 nodes. Out of the 5 replicas, 2 replicasserve application connections in `read_only` mode. All the replicas replicate from the master A.

The Source is A, and the Replicas are - B, C, D, P1, P2. P1 and P2 are production replicas where application connections come.

I am confused on how do I plan the upgrade without downtime. If it was simple source-replica replication, it wouldn't have been a problem. [This](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/12/01/upgrade-master-server-minimal-downtime/) Percona blog provides step-by-step guide.

My understanding so far

1. Upgrade slave B, also upgrade rest of the replicas in the topology
2. Change ProxySQL configuration and remove source A from the topology and make new
   source B writeable in the ProxySQL,
3. Stop application, modify the application connection parameters. Meanwhile let B catch
   with A. Use `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on `A` and `SHOW REPLICA STATUS` on `B` to verify the coordinates match. Once they catch up, note `SHOW MASTER STATUS` on `B`.
4. Change replication for all the replicas to the new source B.
5. Once the connections start coming to new source B, old source A is free to be
   upgraded.
6. Once A is upgraded, I can bring it back in the topology to serve as a replica.

Please help me out understanding the process. I am getting confused because of additional slaves and production slaves as well.

Testing of MySQL version 8 is complete and there's green signal for upgrades. I am aware of the things that are supposed to be taken care of before the servers are upgraded and that there's no going back hence backup is important.

Comment: Is PXC a part of the topology?

Comment: @RickJames There’s no Percona Cluster, it’s a simple MySQL master slave replication on Community edition. ProxySQL is used for connection routing.